# I want to know how to use BackgroundWorker so the app won't freeze

Tags: multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a winform application that supposed to get data from web requests and when i hit the start button it works but for those seconds of loading it will not respond and freeze.
I am a beginner and i heard that there is the class backgroundWorker but i can't get it to work on my code without giving me an error something like "you need to use it on the thread you created with".

Here is the code of the button click:

```
WebClient webURL = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = webURL.OpenRead(url);
        htmlDoc.Load(stream);

        HtmlNode chartNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='top40']");

        listBoxChart.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var item in GetChart(chartNode))
        {
            listBoxChart.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Thanks for the replies!

edit:

OK. Here it is:

"Additional information: This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently."
Button click:

```
void btnGetChart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxChart.Items.Clear();
        listBoxChart.Items.Add("Please Wait. . .");
        listBoxChart.Items.Clear();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

backGroundWorker DoWork: (There is more code of the webrequest above but thats the loop):

```
foreach (var item in GetChart(chartNode))
{       
listBoxChart.Items.Add(item);
}
```

It also says this:

"Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBoxChart' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: If you don't know how to use a `BackgroundWorker` you should read one of the many online tutorials. If you know how to use one but are getting an error, you need to post the code and tell us what error you are getting. What you should not do is ask people on the internet to write your code and then drop it in your application without understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

The event is used to write all your code is `DoWork`. You can place all code in that event. Once you call the method `RunWorkerAsync` the `DoWork` event will be raised. after completing whole process, finally `BackgroundWorker` will raise `RunWorkerCompleted` event. where you can  determine the process has been completed.

there is complete example with description you can find that [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)